# Convert rdl report(BI2008) to rdlc(vs2010)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have created a rdl report with some dynamic query in stored procedure. Report in BI preview, displays correctly.But my concern is, I am converting this report to rdlc by just changing the extension. I have set all the report parameter but when i run the report it displays the error "A data source instance has not been supplied for the data soruce". I have visited must of the blogs and all they are taking about is passing data source to the report. But my question is why should i pass the datasource from the UI, all things are written in XML of rdl file when designing and if we are passing the datasource from UI side then why are we designing the report with all the parameter to the stored procedure. If we are passing specific data to the report then why we need report parameters for stored procedures. So, please help me out of this confusion and please give me some idea on error message. I am using vb.net in vs2010 winform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read more blogs about conversion of rdl to rdlc and i found that rld and rldc functionality is quite different because of data source they take.